# How do I find a balance for negative tests in TDD?

Tags: tdd

Let's imagine we need to develop an app that simply shows you the local outside temperature. So, when you TDD you would write a test case:

```
describe 'App'
  it 'shows the local temperature'
```

That's it. A week later you realise people would pay for seeing full local weather forecast, so you continue TDD:

```
describe 'App'
  it 'shows the local temperature'
  describe 'when they pay me 5$'
    it 'shows full weather forecast'
```

However, some people recommend to add a negative test to avoid false positives:

```
describe 'App'
  it 'shows the local temperature'
  it 'does not show full weather forecast'
    describe 'when they pay me 5$'
      it 'shows full weather forecast'

// or even

describe 'App'
  it 'shows the local temperature'
    describe 'when scrooge'
      it 'does not show full weather forecast'
    describe 'when they pay me 5$'
      it 'shows full weather forecast'
```

While this **will** prevent accidentally allowing not paying users to see the full weather forecast, this is not really scalable (imagine we have a lot of access layers, for example).

The question is: is there any well known or established practice that balances false positive tests in TDD?

Comment: Or you can re-phrase first test to `it 'shows only local temperature'` - where you will test, that output contains only expected values

Comment: I wouldn't call what you ask about *false positives*. I prefer a term *negative test case*, defined as: *a test case that was created for the
purpose of exercising a program in a way that was not explicitly specified in the requirement.* (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0188/4dd5b99b017c0797e42c1c3f2405e8d1805c.pdf). A *false positive* in the domain of testing would be *a test failing though SUT works properly* (http://xunitpatterns.com/false%20positive.html)

Comment: @KrzysztofJelski edited the question, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is No. Just to give you a bit of a context, it all comes down to the importance of the requirements around negative tests. In the example you've given, if it is important for the users to prevent accidentally allowing not paying to see the full weather forecast, then you would consider adding (TDD) negative tests.

However generally with TDD, you write a positive test first, build your software for "happy path" scenarios. This way you have a working software first. TDD is all about designing in small.

Then if the requirements are critical around negative scenarios, then you would consider adding them later. This could be that once the software is in testing phase, you may identify that certain negative tests are critical. Therefore you can start adding them as required. Remember to have a mind set you only need to add them when they are absolutely needed.

Comment: I strongly disagree that this has anything to do with requirements importance. In TDD you do minimal working implementation so with addition of `shows full weather forecast` test minimal working implementation is to show full forecast regardless of whether user paid or not. In order to implement the requirement `when they pay me` you need to add some test that would check negative case as well.

Comment: Well I don't necessarily agree. You could add negative test cases, if the developer decide that testing negative requirements are important - which is usually driven by experience (defensive programming), and requirements.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the answer and can't fit it into the TDD world. In the context of the minimal working implementation argument can you elaborate on how (as in at what moment) the piece of code that disallows to display full forecast for user that did not pay will appear in the code if developer are doing TDD and do not create a test for this?

Answer (score 1):

> However, some people recommend to add a negative test to avoid false
>   positives:

It doesn't avoid false positives. A false positive would be `it 'shows the local temperature'` passing while the application doesn't really show the temperature.

As Spock pointed out, systematically adding negative tests (tests that check that something *doesn't* happen) is problematic because there is no end to what can be tested that way.

I usually write *regression tests* for bugs that did happen in reality but rarely take chances at checking stuff that could hypothetically go wrong in a number of fuzzy ways.

Comment: That would actually be a false negative. A bit counter-intuitive, I know. But let's refer to a well-established source http://xunitpatterns.com/false%20negative.html.

Comment: I don't know that many dev teams call their red tests "positives", but YMMV. In the medical sector maybe ;) Thanks for pointing that out anyway.

Comment: Also, the original question makes even less sense to me with "false positive" defined that way.

Comment: You're right. I commented on the original question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking this is to rephrase the feature as "The app shows full weather *if and only if* the user has paid."

Then it's a matter of taste if you test this in one method or two methods. Something like this as pseudocode:

```
userSeesFullWeatherOnMainPageIfAndOnlyHeHasPaid:
    freeUser = aNewUser()
    freeUser.getsMainPage()
    freeUser.shallNotSeeFullWeather()

    paidUser = aNewUser()
    paidUser.paysForFullWeather()
    paidUser.getsMainPage()
    paidUser.shallSeeFullWeather()
```